# Disabling DynamoDB stream leads to inconsistency between tfstate file and tf config files

Tags: terraform, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am seeing an issue with dynamodb stream where if "stream_enabled" is set to "false" but the "stream_view_type" is set to a variable, in this case it is set to "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES", when running tf apply via our pipeline it produces an error: "Error: error updating DynamoDB Table....ValidationException: Table has no stream to disable:". In which case I will have to go into the AWS account, turn Streams back on for the table, and then rerun the pipeline so terraform turns the stream off. Instead of terraform noticing that stream is already turned off and does nothing. Anyone seen this before? (table name blurred).

[image]

[image: dynamodb module]

The variables are being pulled from a different repo. but its set to the what I mentioned earlier. So lets say I merge a pr with this code in it and the database has already been deployed from a previous deployment, terraform will throw this error even though the db streams are already disabled in the aws account.

Comment: Can you add any code you have and output of plan/apply?

Comment: Have you checked the module documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the stream_view_type from the terraform attribute.